# Outlook 2010 says "File is in use by another application or user" while closing

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook opens, gets new emails and everything but when I close it, it gives me the following error and then opens up a Save a File window after I cancel this error message.

[image: Error message]

There's no other computer that may be using Outlook under this User Name because I just set-up a brand new User Name. However, Colligo Briefcase is attached to the Outlook and not sure if this is triggering and if so how I address the issue!? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it was pointing to the file NormailEmail.dotm in Share folder in the Server which is not suppose to. We had to go and change the Template File Location from "User template" to "Workgroup template" through Word Options => Advanced => File Locations and it solved the problem!